# How to create QR Code using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, qr-code

I need to generate QR Code For every user in my portal. When they logged in, the QR Code Image will be displayed in Their Profile Page.
The QR Code Information Like as follows **http://mywebsite.com/my.html?userId=12345678900987654321**

How to generate QR Code  using AngularJS. If They Scan It directly open into browser. Is it Possible?

Comment: Well, there are a lot of AngularJS libraries to generate QR Codes... This [one](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode) or [this one](https://github.com/janantala/angular-qr), etc.

Comment: Off-Topic, please post here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely be using AngularJs for that. Check out some JavaScript libraries for that purpose, I found Qrcode.js. On their github page they show how to use it.
By the looks of it you will generate a code for a line and user id so samples from their github help:

```
<div id="qrcode"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userId = getUserId(); // get user id somehow
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrCodeElement"), "http://mywebsite.com/my.html?userId=" + userId);
</script>
```

So when you have a HTML element with ID "qrCodeElement" it should show there.